# Запрос file_get_contents выдает "Connection timed out", с curl работает

Tags: php, сервер

file_get_contents("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
Уходит в таймаут, "failed to open stream: Connection timed out in "
Тот же запрос с curl_exec() работает на ура.

Где-то настройки сервера, возможно после апгрейта ПХП, но где, может у кого идеи есть?

CentOS,PHP 5.6.30

Comment: Так и используйте курл. Зачем изобретать велосипед? Курл работает? -Работает. Ну и отлично! :)

Answer (score 1):

Просто на сервере википедии в настройках allow_url_fopen = false поэтому и не получается прочитать данные. Для таких целей используется curl.